# Swift Button action to change label text not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, validation

I am new to IOS and was trying to create a user in one view, when I tried to validate the information from user input, I found it's hard to put text on the label to indicate errors.

My codes :

```
    @IBAction func btnDone1(_ sender: Any) {
    print("button pressed")
    if !isValidEmail(email: (txtRegUName.text)!){
        thisLable.text="This is not a valid email address"
        print("This is not a valid email")
        return
    }
    else{
        if (txtRegP.text!) != (txtRegPAgain.text!){
            thisLable.text="Password not match"
            print("Password not match"+txtRegP.text!+txtRegPAgain.text!)
        }
        else{
            print("All good")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "regToLogin", sender: self)
           }
    }
}
```

i don't know why the label is missing all the desired text I want to assign to, but print function works.

Please advise any mistake I have made.

Comment: Did you hide UILabel in storyboard.

Comment: Give white space thisLabel.text = "Password not match" like that

Comment: Can you check label constraint also if you miss any of the constraint UILabel will not display.

Comment: @GowriG, No, I didn't , just double checked, it's enabled, and disable is un-checked.

Comment: can you post your design

Comment: Oh, yes, the constraint makes the label out of the view, thank you @GowriG

Comment: Before this button's action, have you added a text in the label? And, is it showing on screen? If not, I'll suggest you to add a text in the label and check on the simulator, if it is coming up or not.

Comment: thank @Rob,yes, the constraint causes the problem. I fixed that.

Comment: what's the content of the thisLable all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same way and it is working for me. you can check the screenshot as well. please let me know if text colour of  thisLable.text is in black colour. also if that label is hidden or not.

[image: check]